# Unable to run Shopify Theme App Extension

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

I have a Shopify Remix App running perfectly with `npm run dev`

However when I follow this [guide](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/online-store/theme-app-extensions/getting-started#step-1-create-a-new-extension) to generate Theme app extnsion:
And run `npm run shopify app generate extension`

It does not work anymore
[image]

I already tried this but it does not solve the issue https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-cli/issues/2050